# Will this work while copying a string?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I'm trying to copy PIN (there is data inside PIN) to temp. (Assuming PIN is always smaller than temp)

```
const char * PIN;
.... 
char [10] temp  ="";
int i = 0; 
while (*(PIN+i)) {
    temp[i] = (PIN+i)*;
    i++;
}
```

Also would it be okay if I treated temp like a pointer as such?

```
long int res = strtol (&temp, NULL, 10);
```

Comment: You need to dereference the pointer, PIN+1, as follows: "*(PIN+i)" or "PIN[i]".  It would be simpler to just use the C library function: "strcpy (temp, PIN) ;".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things,

temp ="\0"
Will actually put two \0 in the string, the one you wrote, and one implied by the quotation.

PIN+i needs to be dereferenced (with a *) or it will go on and on unless you can guarantee a null pointer at the end of the address space.

```
while (*(PIN+i))
```

Then to copy the characters rather than the pointers the assignment statement should also be dereferenced.

```
temp[i]=*(PIN+i);
i++; // Because the pointer needs to be incremented
```

Also why wouldn't you just use strcpy? or strncpy?

Comment: strcpy is a longer operation I believe isn't it?

Comment: pretty sure the def is something like
while (*src)
{
   *dest=*src
   *src++;
   *dest++;
}
Pretty lean but doesn't check for NULL and the end of the source string. Plus I wouldn't worry about the length of the operation at this point in your coding. Leave optimization till last :)

Comment: I might have some race conditions going on my code, trying to cut down sometime to avoid a ton of headache!

Answer (score 2):

No!

`PIN+i` does not change any state. It will be true while `PIN` plus `i` is not equal to zero. Since `PIN` is a random memory address, that's a bad idea.

If you want to copy a string, look at `strcpy`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add i++! Also I'm assuming that PIN ends with a null carriage '\0'

Comment: @Falcata If PIN ends with a NUL character, just `strcpy(temp, PIN);`.